# Is there a material which slows down light to the point where the "head" of a laser beam can be seen as it passes through?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, laser

Is there a material which slows light down to the point where the front tip, or "head" of a laser beam, can be seen passing through, either with high-speed photography, or even the naked eye?

Imagine pointing a simple, cheap laser pointer at said block of material. The tip of the laser beam could be seen moving through the material, almost as a bullet can be seen moving through ballistic gelatin with a high-speed camera.

Comment: You don't even need a special material for this; femtophotography allows one to photograph light as it propagates (http://web.media.mit.edu/~raskar/trillionfps/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a material that would work the way you imagine.  However, "light in flight holography" accomplishes much the same thing.  See wikipedia "light-in-flight- imaging".